# Does force depend on the frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames

From Newton's second law if mass is not constant,

$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)=ma+\frac{dm}{dt}v$$

So Force depends on velocity. And Velocity depends on the frame of reference. So does force depend on the frame of reference?

Comment: Describe a scenario where dm/dv is not zero .

Comment: Maybe rockets? I didn't think of scenarios. But here my concern is different. If we assume mass can vary with time, will the force depend on the frame of reference?

Comment: I think $\frac{dm}{dt}v$ is thrust force? In that case, $v$ would actually be the relative velocity of the ejected mass.